# Adding columns to Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to add columns to a Google Sheets, but I get an error. I need to add a copy of the previous column.

Code:

```
def insert_column():
   sa = gspread.service_account(filename="service_account.json")
   sh = sa.open("**NAME**")
   wks = sh.worksheet("Class Data")

   data = {
       "requests": [
           {
               "insertDimension": {
                   "range": {
                       "sheetId": 0,
                       "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                       "startIndex": 4,
                       "endIndex": 5
                   },
                   "inheritFromBefore": True
               }
           },
       ],
   }

   wks.batch_update(data).execute()
```

An Error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I think the problem is here `wks.batch_update(data).execute()` , but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code. This way other users can run your code and diagnose the error

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the document of gspread, it seems that `batch_update(body)` is the method of class gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet. But, you are using this method as the method of class gspread.worksheet.Worksheet. I think that this is the reason for your issue of `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. And also, `execute()` is not required to be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```py
def insert_column():
   sa = gspread.service_account(filename="service_account.json")
   sh = sa.open("**NAME**")
   # wks = sh.worksheet("Class Data") # In this script, this line is not used.

   data = {
       "requests": [
           {
               "insertDimension": {
                   "range": {
                       "sheetId": 0, # <--- Please set the sheet ID of "Class Data" sheet.
                       "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                       "startIndex": 4,
                       "endIndex": 5
                   },
                   "inheritFromBefore": True
               }
           },
       ],
   }

   sh.batch_update(data)
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your service account can access to the Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)

Comment: To the user who downvoted. When I tested my proposed script again, I confirmed that the OP's error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` was removed, and the script worked. From this situation, I cannot understand the reason for your action. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If my answer has modification points, please tell me. I would like to confirm it and improve my answer. If you can cooperate to improve this answer, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?